# Giving Realative Path in Java

Tags: java, relative-path

```
Vzips-server -| 
              |--Javaresources>>src>>packagename>>email.java
              |--WebContent>>images>>logo.jpg
```

i am trying to insert logo.jpg into email.java by giving relative path.

I am either getting either Null Pointer exception or file not found exception.

can you suggest me how do I give the relative path

```
BodyPart image= new MimeBodyPart()
DataSource fds=new FileDataSource(new File("../WebContent/images/logo.jpg"))
```

Comment: You should have it in the classpath if you use it from Java code.

Comment: correct, but how will it work if I deploy the code in different server.In my local machine its working but not on the server

Comment: If it is part of the jar it is working in all environments

Comment: in Linux environment also? because I need to deploy the code there

Comment: yes also on linux

Answer (score 0):

To find the WebContent Folder Use : `getServletContext().getRealPath("WebContent");`
It returns something like : `var/share/tomcat/webapps/YourApplicationName/WebContent` i think this is what you need!